# (.bat) How to bulk change file with a certain name

Tags: batch-file

I'm new here and new to batch, I want to change all files named squelette-*.html (delete all " inside them)

My code look like this :

```
    @echo off

    if not exist squelette-0.html ( type nul > squelette-0.html )

    set ligne1="<!DOCTYPE html>"
    set ligne2="<html lang="fr">"
    set ligne3="<head>"
    set ligne4="<title> </title>"
    set ligne5="<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">"
    set ligne6="<style type="text/css">"
    set ligne7="body {"
    set ligne8="}"
    set ligne9="</style>"
    set ligne10="</head>"
    set ligne11="<body>"
    set ligne12="<p>"
    set ligne13="</p>"

    @echo %ligne1% > squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne2% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne3% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne4% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne5% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne6% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne7% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne8% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne9% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne10% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne11% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne12% >> squelette-0.html
    @echo %ligne13% >> squelette-0.html
```

and I want squelette-0.html to look like this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <styletype="text/css">
    body {
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    </p>
```

When I try to delete them from the variables, I get a weird error :

```
    File not found
    File name not valid
```

(translated by myself from french)

Or if my way is bad, can someone help me and create a better one ?
(My final idea is to reproduce [this script](https://github.com/ATField2501/magik_html/blob/1ce6f3bedc0966fe324e581916081dc5497d5024/magik_html.sh) in batch)

Comment: Don't assign quotes to the variables and escape the special characters with the ^ symbol.

Comment: special symbols are " and spaces ?

Comment: How about the > symbol. That should be pretty apparent considering you are using it to write to a file but need them in your output. The < is also special because it is used to redirect standard input.

Comment: There is an interactive tool here https://pacificblue.software/download/file_smith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off

< NUL (
    set /P "=<!DOCTYPE html>"   & echo/
    set /P "=<html lang="fr">"  & echo/
    set /P "=<head>"            & echo/
    set /P "=<title> </title>"  & echo/
    set /P "=<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">" & echo/
    set /P "=<style type="text/css">" & echo/
    set /P "=body {"            & echo/
    set /P "=}"                 & echo/
    set /P "=</style>"          & echo/
    set /P "=</head>"           & echo/
    set /P "=<body>"            & echo/
    set /P "=<p>"               & echo/
    set /P "=</p>"              & echo/
) > squelette-0.html
```

The `set /P` command allows to enclose in parentheses its "prompt" so it is not necessary to escape the special characters. However, it does not show a LF at end of line, so it is necessary to add an `echo/` command after each line. Also, `set /P` *read* a line, so it is necessary to redirect its input to `< NUL`.

Comment: Thank you, i will try when i will be able to :)